# ArcPy Dissolve Statistics Fields - fixed into variable

Tags: arcpy, dissolve

How can I change this fixed POP column into my variable: field = parameters[1].valueAsText. It says syntax error everytime.

```
StatField = "POP MIN;POP MAX"

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features, region_Dissolve, "Class", StatField, "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

Comment: yes, this is it, I applied "field" into it and it works. Thank you

Comment: You should post your working code as an **answer** =)